# AngularJS + Rails $scope model is updated but not firing a re-render

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Not sure if I'm using Angular correctly. I basically want to make a simple Link/Story sharing site.

```
  var Story = $resource("api/stories/:id", {}, {
    query: { method: "GET", isArray: false }
  });

  Story.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.stories = data.stories;
    $scope.test = 1;
  });

  $scope.submitForm = function(formData) {
    Story.save({}, formData, function(data) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.stories = data.stories;
        $scope.test = 2;
      });
    });
  }
```

Changes to `$scope.test` get reflected, but not stories.

Edit: Uhhh so apparently if I remove "ng-controller"

```
<ul ng-controller="storyController">
  <li ng-repeat="story in stories">{{ story.title }}</li>
  <p>{{ test }}</p>
</ul>
```

Everything works now..... I'm not even sure why....

Comment: how do you use `stories`?

Comment: launch debug in browser and look at 'data' object

Comment: I'm just using ng-repeat to go through all the stories

Answer (score 0):

In the `query()` method, you are setting `$scope.stories` to an Array however, it appears you are then attempting to set `$scope.stories` to, what I assuming, is a single story object.  What exactly are you expecting to see when `$scope.stories` changes?  A new story in the list of stories?  If so, you need to do the following:

```
$scope.stories.push(data.stories);
```

You are not replacing the array, you are adding a new index to it.

Comment: My create api method returns a new list of stories and my intentions were to set the current scope stories to that new list. I'm assuming after my save it receives an array of stories + the one I just created. Then if I set scope.stories to that new list, it will update

Answer (score 0):

Okay so apparently the answer was that I had already defined ng-view + a route that assigned a storyController to that view already. I was assigning it twice essentially by adding an ng-controller directive.